# Google map directions: wait until I enter both locations

Tags: google-maps

When I click on the "directions" button in Google maps, it puts "your location" in the start field and immediately starts calculating directions. So if I am looking for a walking route between interesting places in Colchester (England), the app assumes I want a walking route from Rennes (my home city in France), and shows me how to walk 200 km to a ferry and then another 300 km from various English port cities to Colchester. In the process, it zooms the map out to global level so that it can show this profoundly helpful route. Is there a way to modify Google maps so that it simply sits still and quietly waits for me to enter both locations before calculating any directions or moving the map in any way?